# Where do economists look for reliable commodity prices for dairy products?

Tags: pricing

I would like to know the market commodity price of cream cheese.  I know you can look up the price of gold in the Wall Street Journal.  Where can I get info on dairy products like cream cheese?

Comment: I don't generally look up the price of cream cheese in the abstract. If I did, though, I'd probably look to BLS microdata (the Consumer Expenditure Survey and the data that are used as inputs into the Consumer Price Index and Producer Price Index). A lot of the data aren't public, but they do release public use files.

Comment: You can find such (Canadian data) on the subject from here: http://www.statcan.gc.ca/tables-tableaux/sum-som/l01/cst01/econ155a-eng.htm